# Audacity FFmpeg 7.1 AAC export Unsupported number of channels

Tags: ffmpeg

Here is the error I am getting, I took a 7.1 AAC file, and remixed one of the tracks, and now I am trying to export back to the original format.

```
ffmpeg -i - -strict experimental -c:a aac -ac 8 -b:a 240k "F:\Something.aac"

ffmpeg version 2.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
built on May 22 2014 19:56:44 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-    
libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
libavutil      52. 66.100 / 52. 66.100    
libavcodec     55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
libavformat    55. 33.100 / 55. 33.100
libavdevice    55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
libavfilter     4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
libswscale      2.  5.102 /  2.  5.102
libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : 7.1
Input #0, wav, from 'pipe:':
Duration: N/A, bitrate: 5644 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, 7.1, s16, 5644 kb/s
[aac @ 02567320] Unsupported number of channels: 8
Output #0, adts, to 'F:\Something.aac':
Stream #0:0: Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, 7.1, fltp, 240 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16le -> aac)
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ffmpeg` is too old.

You can get a new build for Windows at [Zeranoe](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/). Users of other OSs can find links to builds at the [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page.

Comment: Thanks I went to the windows build page, with shared libraries, and copy and pasted the internals of the bin folder to the FFMPEG for audicity in C:/Program files, and pointed Audacity at the 57.dll library instead of 55.dll and its now processing. I had assumed that Audacity would not work with the new version.